# Error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of null - Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have below code snippet which is giving me an error. I am getting a response back from getFilteredList which is of lenght 1 and it has a proper json data. But not sure why its giving error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of null

```
getFilteredList(group, feature).then(r=>{ //here I am getting error. 
    if(r.data.response_code == "1")
    {
      const columnName = "ColumnName";
      const Codes = r.data.response_message.map(x => x[columnName]);
      Codes.forEach(code=> {
        let store = getStoreValue(code);
        getDetailsById(id, datastore)
        .then(r=>{
          res.status(200).send(r.data);
        }).catch(e=>{
          parseError(e, res);
        });
      })
    }
  }).catch(e=>{
      parseError(e, res);
    });
}
```

Could someone help please.

getFilteredList() is another node js service which itself returns json data and I can see that data in logs. Below is the data it returns.

> {"CODE":"AGR","GRP":"LEND","FEAT_CODE":"SRC_AGREE","GROUP_NAME":"Prop","FEA_NAME":"Property","DISPLAY_NAME":"Property","ROLE_CODE":"LE"}

Thanks.

Comment: Can you at least post the code for `getFilteredList`?

Comment: getFilteredList() a another node js service which is returning  a data when I tested it using Saop UI. I can see it in logs as well of application. I am not getting why it is saying null though having a data, @Quentin

Comment: @Chrillewoodz comment added for your query,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved an error on myself. It was an issue in code which was not calling a appropriate web service and hence getting a null response from service which was not exist itself. I have change the code to call the exact web service and now its working fine. Thanks for support.